# UWP Media Casting with Image as a source, how to update the output

Tags: uwp

I have a UWP app, which has an `Image` control set as a `CastingSource` for a renderer. When I change the control's `Source` property (ie. change the image), the image at the renderer device stays the same, there's no connection's `StateChanged` event at all.

Is it possible that, after the connection is created with an Image as a casting source, the output can be changed? Or do I need to disconnect and reconnect?

Edit: source code:

MainPage.xaml

```
<Image x:Name="image" ManipulationMode="TranslateX" 
  ManipulationCompleted="image_ManipulationCompleted" Tapped="image_Tapped">
  <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
     <behaviors:Blur x:Name="ImageTransitionBehavior" 
       Duration="500" AutomaticallyStart="False" />
  </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
</Image>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
private async void page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var picker = new CastingDevicePicker();
    picker.Filter.SupportsPictures = true;
    picker.CastingDeviceSelected += Picker_CastingDeviceSelected;
    picker.Show(new Windows.Foundation.Rect(50, 50, 100, 100));
}
private async void Picker_CastingDeviceSelected(CastingDevicePicker sender, CastingDeviceSelectedEventArgs args)
{
    await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
    {
        CastingConnection connection = args.SelectedCastingDevice.CreateCastingConnection();

        connection.ErrorOccurred += Connection_ErrorOccurred;
        connection.StateChanged += Connection_StateChanged;

        await connection.RequestStartCastingAsync(image.GetAsCastingSource());

    });
}
```

github: https://github.com/wutipong/ZipPicViewCS/tree/master/ZipPicViewUWP

Comment: Could you please add some example code to for the issue that your are having?

Comment: some source code added.

Comment: May be I'm misunderstanding something... DLNA with image sources should have been listed with all image prepared, not to update the renderer dynamically ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the `Image` control has a way to notify the casting source that something has changed. You should update `CastingConnection.Source` with your control after changing the image.

```
private async Task NextImageAsync()
{
    image.Source = "my new image source";
    await connection.RequestStartCastingAsync(image.GetAsCastingSource());  
}
```

[CastingConnection.Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Media.Casting.CastingConnection)

> Gets and sets the content source that is being casted through the
>   connection to the casting device. The content can be set and changed
>   at any time and doing so does not disconnect the connection.

Comment: From what I see, the connection is disconnected after the `RequestStartCastingAsync` is called. It's probably the device-specific problem, I'll be testing with different renderer when I have another one in hands.